# Custom event binding to checkbox in telerik grid for mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

i have a status column in my model which is true or false.
i show this column on telerik grid for mvc when item is true checkbox is checked and while 
false is unchecked.

Problem is i want bind custom event to checkbox to toggle item status.
How can bind custom event to checkbox and on check or uncheck update item.

I show in grid view :

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Status).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' 
    name='Status' value='<#= Status#>' />");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use jQuery:

```
$("#Grid").delegate("[name=Status]", "click", function() {
    var checkBox = this;
    alert(checkBox.checked);
});
```

or add an onclick attribute to the checkbox:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Status).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='Status' value='<#= Status#>' onclick='checkboxClicked(this)' />");

function checkboxClicked(checkBox) {
    alert(checkBox.clicked);
}
```

Comment: thanks atanas. well have can i get id of this row on action of checkbox?

Comment: columns.Bound(o => o.Status).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='Status' checked='<#= Status#>' value='<#= Status#>' onclick='checkboxClicked(\"<#= Id #>\")' />");  either checked true or false checkbox is checked. why?

Comment: A checkbox is checked if its "checked" attribute is present. This is just how <input type="checkbox" /> works. Check this for a demo how to check checkboxes based on a value of the data: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax